# Go to settings menu upon snackbar being dismissed?

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I have a floating action button that makes a snackbar appear. When the snackbar is dismissed, I would like the user to be redirected to the Settings application of the phone.

This is the current code I have so far.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

                FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
                fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                                final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.fab), msg, Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
                                snackbar.setCallback(new Snackbar.Callback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDismissed(Snackbar snackbar, int event) {
                                                // what goes here?
                                        }
                                });
                        }
                });

                /* putting goToSettings(this) here works fine */
        }

        public static void goToSettings(AppCompatActivity activity) {
                final Intent i = new Intent();
                i.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
                i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + activity.getPackageName()));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
                activity.startActivity(i);
        }

}
```

If I put the `goToSettings()` call outside of the code related to the floating action button, the user will be sent to the Settings application as the last part of the invocation of the `onCreate()` method. However, I want the dismissal of the snackbar created by the floating action button click to cause the user to go to the Settings application, rather than the user automatically being sent there.

I'm almost certain the reason `goToSettings(this)` doesn't work in the `onDismissed()` method is because `this` is no longer referring to the `MainActivity`. But knowing this, how can I redirect the user to the Settings application from the dismissal of the snackbar?

Comment: Use `MainActivity.this` inside your callback method. Or you could drop the `static` and the `AppCompatActivity` parameter, and just use the methods directly in `goToSettings()`, if that's the only place you're going to use it.

Comment: @MikeM. That's really interesting. Using `MainActivity.this` in the callback method worked, but I don't know why it works.

Comment: Your reasoning about `this` in the callback method was correct. An unqualified `this` refers to the immediate enclosing object, which there is the anonymous `Snackbar.Callback` instance you're creating. When you qualify it by using `MainActivity.this`, the compiler then knows that you want the current `MainActivity` instance.